# SDL Frame-Rate Cap

Tags: c++, sdl, frame-rate

I have a working code that is able to limit the fps of my game. However i get 20% CPU usage with this method, and by using renderer v-sync i get a percentage close to 0 (with the same fps).

i think this is caused by the main loop that runs more times than the fps i want. i'm wondering if there is a better method to cap the fps. i'll leave here my code:

```
while(!quit){
    std::chrono::microseconds delta=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()-previous_time_point);
    time_elapsed+=delta;
    previous_time_point+=delta;
        
    if(FRAME_TIME<=time_elapsed){
        time_elapsed-=FRAME_TIME;
        //DO STUFF
    }
```

Comment: You are not using any `sleep`, so CPU constantly calculates deltas. Otherwise, frame synchronization is a big topic and can't usually be answered in terms "what's the best".

Comment: Typically, if `time_elapsed < FRAME_TIME`, you can sleep for approximately `FRAME_TIME - time_elapsed`. Perhaps a bit less, but it's not going to be precise anyway.

Comment: If you `sleep_until` a time point, as opposed to `sleep_for` a duration, you don't have to compute the time duration to sleep.  Instead you just keep incrementing a time point to sleep until by the frame rate.  This eliminates a call to now() on every iteration.  If you sleep slightly less than called for, you can busy-loop the remaining bit.  This gives you a trade-off parameter you can tweak to get the desired accuracy/cpu-usage tradeoff that is best for your application.